# Cómo recorrer un array bidimencional?

Tags: php, html5, array, csv, phpexcel

verán estoy iniciándome en php y estoy un poco trabado en el manejo de los arrays bidimencionales y multidimencionales; espero puedan ayudarme y nutrirme de conocimientos.
He hecho una función que recibe como parámetro un archivo con extensión csv, crea un array asociativo y al final la función retorna dicho array.
Aquí muestro la función:

```
    function utf8_fopen_read($csv) { 
     $fc = iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', file_get_contents($csv)); 
       $handle=fopen("php://memory", "rw"); 
         fwrite($handle, $fc); 
         fseek($handle, 0); 
         return $handle; 
             }
    function archivoCsv ($filecsv) {
    $info = array();
    $file = utf8_fopen_read ($filecsv);
    if ($file !== FALSE) {
    $filesname = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",");
    $files_n = count($filesname);
    while (($infor = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
     // array asociativo
      for ($i = 0; $i < $files_n; $i++) {
        $inf[$filesname[$i]] = $infor[$i];
       }

        $info[] = $inf;
     }
       fclose($file);
           return $info;

             }
           }

    $resultado = array();
    $cSV = "personas.csv";
    $resultado = archivoCsv($cSV);
    echo "El array resultado tiene  " . count($resultado) . " sub-arrays <br><br>";
```

el archivo personas.csv tiene en su interior algo más o menos como esto:

```
Nombre,Apellido,Genero,Edad,EstadoCivil,Nacionalidad -> esta linea de aca 
son los nombres de los campos.
Antonio,Grajales,Masculino,35,Soltero,Argentino -> estos los valores
Mauricio,Paredas,Masculino,29,Casado,Uruguayo
Elena,Lopez,Femenino,32,Viuda,Colombiana
Evangelina,Ochoa,22,Soltera,Ecuatoriana
```

hasta aqui todo me va bien, pero he intentado utilizar el array $resultado como parametro en otra función, que pueda hacer algunas operaciones con ese array como sumar algunas de sus columnas, etc... y que al final, una vez haya hecho dichas sumas, con el resultado pueda volver a crear un nuevo array bidimencional (algo asi como un array con valores actualizados) y retornarlo. :

```
    function nueva ($resultado)
      {
           //aqui he intentado con un for hacer que se muestren los valores del array resultado que estoy pasando como parametro pero me muestra error, algo referente a que tengo un problema en los argumentos para el for. intente con un foreach y fue lo mismo. No he llegado hasta las sumas de sus columnas ya que me quede trabado en mostrar el contenido del array.

      return $nuevo_array_actualizado;
        }
     $array_nuevo = array();
      $array_nuevo = nueva ($resultado);
```

probablemente es un tonteria y se resulve facilmente, pero no se, estoy trabado. Alguien que pueda echarme una mano? Lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: puedes mostrar como queda tu array $resultado? o sea, después de generarlo con la función archivoCsv($cSV);

Answer (score 1):

Para recorrer el array podés tomarlo como un array simple de un nivel, por ejemplo:

```
$i=0;
    $new_m = array();
    $newSubArray = array();
    foreach ($resultado as $item) {
        foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
            $newSubArray[$key] = $value;
            echo "Key: " . $key . " Value: ". $value ."<br>";
        }
        echo "------<br>";
        $new_m[$i] = $newSubArray;
        $i++; 
    }

    echo "Array final: ".json_encode($new_m);
```

Esto te permite tomar cada key y su valor del array y poder trabajar de manera más directa. Es aquí donde podes hacer el tratamiento con algunas columnas (como sumar por ejemplo) y luego guardar el resultado en el array $newSubArray. La salida de el código que te dejé a modo de ejemplo es:

```
Key: Nombre Value: Antonio
Key: Apellido Value: Grajales
Key: Gnero Value: Masculino
Key: Edad Value: 35
Key: EstadoCivil Value: Soltero
Key: Nacionalidad Value: Argentino
------
Key: Nombre Value: Luis
Key: Apellido Value: Morales
Key: Gnero Value: Masculino
Key: Edad Value: 40
Key: EstadoCivil Value: Casado
Key: Nacionalidad Value: Argentino
------
Array final: [{"Nombre":"Antonio","Apellido":"Grajales","Gnero":"Masculino","Edad":"35","EstadoCivil":"Soltero","Nacionalidad":"Argentino"},{"Nombre":"Luis","Apellido":"Morales","Gnero":"Masculino","Edad":"40","EstadoCivil":"Casado","Nacionalidad":"Argentino"}]
```

Nota: podés codificar el array a json, y así tener una manera más fácil de trabajar.

Comment: Gracias!! Ahora si se muestra mi array. Ahora estoy aprendiendo como hacer cierta suma con una columna, es un lio y me enreda un poco, pero me sirve para aprender, al menos ya tengo claro el error que estaba cometiendo al mostrar el array que retorna la función archivocSV. Muchas gracias por ayudarme con eso. Me funciona su codigo de ejemplo